# converting string of binary into data matrix in R

Tags: r

How can i turn M unto a 12 by m matrix of numbers 
(e.g. with one bit per cell):

```
library(R.utils)
m<-5    
k<-12   
W<-sample(1:(2**m),k)
M<-matrix(intToBin(V),k,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intToBin` is returning characters, so use `strsplit` to break it into individual digits (bits) before putting in a matrix.

```
m <- 5
k <- 12
W <- sample(1:(2**m), k)
M <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(intToBin(W), ""))), nrow= k, byrow = TRUE)
> M
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    1    1    0
 [4,]    0    1    0    0    1    1
 [5,]    0    1    0    1    1    0
 [6,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    1    1    1    1    0
 [9,]    1    1    0    1    0    1
[10,]    1    0    0    1    1    1
[11,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[12,]    0    0    1    1    0    1
```

Comment: hey, you should add an option byrow=TRUE to that matrix() or it won't work as advertised:)

Answer (score 2):

`intToBin` will return a character string of the binary representation.

You can split this string, convert to integer, then combine the rows.

```
 M<-do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(intToBin(W),''), as.integer))
```